# How to indent the selected line one "tab" forward or backward

Tags: indentation, tabs

In a lot of text editors there is a keystroke used to move the selected lines one "tab" to the right, usually 4 whitespace or one "tab" to the left.
How can I do this in emacs? I have only found automatic indentation like C-M-|

Comment: While this is indeed useful sometimes, an experienced Emacs user would rarely need this. Can you share the reason for needing this functionality? It might be the case that the original problem can be solved differently, but in a more efficient / smart way.

Answer (score 2):

There's some commands starting with the name `indent-rigidly`, which indents by whitespace. The base command `indent-rigidly` is bound to `C-x TAB` by default, and lets you use the arrow keys to indent the region (left/right to indent one space, shift + left/right to indent by tab stops).

Instead of `indent-rigidly` you might want to use `indent-rigidly-left-to-tab-stop` or `indent-rigidly-right-to-tab-stop`, but they have no default key bindings.